# I try to compare two Collections of int arrays and I've got results which origin I don't understand

Tags: java

I am solving this kata on Codewars: https://www.codewars.com/kata/635fc0497dadea0030cb7936
this is my code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] ms;

        ms = new int[][] {{1, 2, 3, 4},
                {3, 1, 4, 2},
                {4, 3, 2, 1},
                {2, 4, 1, 3}};
        System.out.println(count_different_matrices(ms));
    }


    private static final Set<int[]> registeredM = new HashSet<>();
    static public int count_different_matrices(int[][] matrices) {
        Arrays.stream(matrices).forEach(m -> {
        if(unwrapPossibleMatrices(m).stream().noneMatch(registeredM::contains)) {
            registeredM.add(m);

        }});
        registeredM.forEach(e -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(e)));
        return registeredM.size();
    }

    static private List<int[]> unwrapPossibleMatrices(int[] m) {
        return Arrays.asList(new int[][]{
                m,
                {m[2], m[0], m[3], m[1]},
                {m[3], m[2], m[1], m[0]},
                {m[1], m[3], m[0], m[2]}
        });
    }
```

Output received in the console:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[2, 4, 1, 3]
[4, 3, 2, 1]
[3, 1, 4, 2]
4
```

I expected output of only `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, My train of thought was that `contains()` should invoke `a.equals(b)` where `a` and `b` in this example is of type `int[]` and when they will be compared by equals - it will check if length and elements in the arrays match. Instead what happened (I think) was that address of the object was checked - thus, giving different results for arrays with the same elements. My question is the following: how to modify this code to check actual elements passed in arrays?

Comment: HashSet depends on equals and hashcode but arrays don't override those methods. Instead they inherit them from java.lang.Object which means it depends on objects *reference* rather than *content*. Solution depends on what you want and are willing to do. You can for instance start using Lists instead of arrays, they override `equals` and `hashcode` properly. OR you could create your own class like `Row` which will wrap `int[]` array and provide implementation for equals/hashcode and use that with HashSet.

Comment: You can also use TreeSet instead of HashSet and provide Comparator which for equal arrays will return 0, and negative/positive arrays if one will be *smaller/bigger* than other.

Comment: (fix) "...and negative/positive [number] if one will be *smaller/bigger* than other."

Comment: Ok, I checked right now and it looks like there are two implementations of equals in the Arrays class: static provided by Arrays itself; which acts as I thought - comparing elements and length and equals inherited from Object which acts just like == operator. Thx I will try with TreeSet : )

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I've changed my solution as @Pshemo pointed out (thank you :)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] ms;

        ms = new int[][] {{1, 2, 3, 4},
                {3, 1, 4, 2},
                {4, 3, 2, 1},
                {2, 4, 1, 3}};
        System.out.println(count_different_matrices(ms));
    }
    
    private static final Set<Row> registeredM = new HashSet<>();
    static public int count_different_matrices(int[][] matrices) {
        registeredM.clear();
        Arrays.stream(matrices).forEach(m -> {
        if(unwrapPossibleMatrices(m).stream().noneMatch(registeredM::contains)) {
            registeredM.add(new Row(m));

        }});
        registeredM.forEach(e -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(e.row())));
        return registeredM.size();
    }

    private static List<Row> unwrapPossibleMatrices(int[] m) {
        return Arrays.asList(
                new Row(m), 
                new Row(new int[]{m[2], m[0], m[3], m[1]}), 
                new Row(new int[]{m[3], m[2], m[1], m[0]}), 
                new Row(new int[]{m[1], m[3], m[0], m[2]})
        );
    }

    record Row(int[] row) {
        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Arrays.hashCode(row);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
            Row row1 = (Row) o;
            return Arrays.equals(row, row1.row);
        }
    }
```